# Deserialise JSON into an ASP.Net generic-list derived class

Tags: asp.net, json, serialization

Using the ASP.Net 4.5 [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) class, is it possible to deserialise a JSON string directly into a generic-list derived class?

For example, if I have the following, it works...

```
public class MyClass {
  public int Id { get; set; }
}
string json = "[{\"Id\":1},{\"Id\":2}]";
var ser = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var myList = (List<MyClass>)ser.Deserialize<List<MyClass>>(json);
```

But if I want to have a collection of `MyClass` by deriving from `List<MyClass>` (so that the class can contain functions for dealing with the data) and do the following...

```
public class MyClasses : List<MyClass> { ... }
```

Then I can't get it to deserialise...

```
var myList = ser.Deserialize<MyClasses>(json);
```

As I get the following runtime error (the code does compile)

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyClass]' to type 'MyClasses'.

If possible I'd like to avoid external libraries

---

One solution I've just figured out is to do the following, by giving MyClasses an extra constructor that takes a `List<MyClass>`.

```
public class MyClasses : List<MyClass> {
  public MyClasses() { }
  public MyClasses(List<MyClass> classes) {
    foreach(var class in classes)
      this.Add(class);
  }
  ...
}
```

And then pass that to a new instance of the class...

```
var myList = new MyClasses(ser.Deserialize<MyClasses>(json));
```

I would still appreciate any thoughts on a better approach to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this using `Newtonsoft.Json`:

```
string json = "[{\"Id\":1},{\"Id\":2}]";
var myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(json);
```

Comment: *If possible I'd like to avoid external libraries* - do you have an answer without using an external library?  It also looks like you've completely avoided the point of the question which was to deserialise into `MyClasses`

Comment: Isn't MyClasses just a list of MyClass?

Comment: In my example, yes... but it will have a large number of functions that deal with the data